# Swift -sort array by substring

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of strings (they were urls that are casted to strings), in the middle of each string they all have a `UUID().uuidString` with a count variable and a .jpg in them.

```
let arr = [ htps://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/myApp.appspot.com/o/users%Mxd6EUO5l2LK-mKa%2F4606E275-B2C5-4A69-B997-01423ABFE3B7%2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_3.jpg?alt=media&token=e215e6a1-f5b9-431e-83a3,

htps://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/myAapp.appspot.com/o/users%-Ll_Mxd6EUO5l2LK-mKa%2F4606E275-B2C5-4A69-B997-01423ABFE3B7%2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_1.jpg?alt=media&token=f350cf36-4c4e-4faf,

htps://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/myAPp.appspot.com/o/users%mKa%2F4606E275-B2C5-4A69-B997-01423ABFE3B7%2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_2.jpg?alt=media&token=123uyqtr

....]
```

The first element has this in the middle of it: **2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_3.jpg**

The second element has this in the middle of it: **2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_1.jpg**

The third element has this in the middle of it: **2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_2.jpg**

The fourth element and on and on ..

How can I sort these strings in this array based on either the substring of the **UUID** with the **_x.jpg** or just the **_x.jpg** alone?

FYI I have access to the UUID beforehand

Comment: You want to sort them by the number of the `jpg`?

Comment: yes because that's what they all have in common that can be used for sorting

Comment: Split your string with `_` . Here first part is UDID and second part is the **x.jpg** . Now you can sort accordingly.

Comment: @dahiya_boy thanks for the advice. I'm going to Shahid's answer. It's basically what you said

Comment: Rather than mapping your `UUID` into `URL`s and then `String`s, make them into a `[UUID: URL]`. Sort the dict by its keys, and then take its values. For these purposes `[(UUID, URL)]` would work just as well, too.

Comment: @Alexander hey thanks! Interesting concept, The thing is I have an array of images, I loop through them and in the firebase storage callback the url gets generated. I'd have to extract the uuid from the url first and then do what you said. You have a good idea but because firebase was giving me the uuid's in no particular order, shahid's answer worked fine. Thanks :)

Comment: @LanceSamaria I was going off what you said with "FYI I have access to the UUID beforehand". I was under the impression that you had the UUIDS, made URLs out of them, and then made Strings out of the URLs. In such a case, parsing the UUIDs out of the strings is needlessly complicated, because you would just have the original UUIDs available to you directly

Comment: @Alexander I actually do add the uuid, underscore, and count to the url. I append it all to the end of the url but firebase appends the other stuff you see in each string to the end of it so the uuid ends up in the middle of the string. I like your idea though!

Comment: @LanceSamaria Is it only adding on the query params, like `?alt=media&token=123uyqtr`?

Comment: @Alexander yes it does. Here's how I create the ref, the uuid is actually a property that's why each url has the same exact uuid, I add an underscore and count to differentiate them: let imageRef = Storage....reference?.child(postId).child("\(uuid)_\(count).jpg"). In the imageRef?.putData(imageData)... callback there is another call that generates the url: imageRef?.downloadURL(completion: ... and that downLoadUrl.absoluteString is what you see in the array from my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197587/discussion-between-alexander-and-lance-samaria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your starting array is something like this

```
let array = ["htps://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/myApp.appspot.com/o/users%Mxd6EUO5l2LK-mKa%2F4606E275-B2C5-4A69-B997-01423ABFE3B7%2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_3.jpg?alt=media&token=e215e6a1-f5b9-431e-83a3","htps://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/myAapp.appspot.com/o/users%-Ll_Mxd6EUO5l2LK-mKa%2F4606E275-B2C5-4A69-B997-01423ABFE3B7%2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_1.jpg?alt=media&token=f350cf36-4c4e-4faf","htps://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/myAPp.appspot.com/o/users%mKa%2F4606E275-B2C5-4A69-B997-01423ABFE3B7%2FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_2.jpg?alt=media&token=123uyqtr"]
```

Give this one a try.

You can split based on your `jpg` suffix, and then based on your `UUID`.

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in

let firstIndex = Int((first.components(separatedBy: ".jpg")[0]).components(separatedBy: "FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_")[1]) ?? -1
let secondIndex = Int((second.components(separatedBy: ".jpg")[0]).components(separatedBy: "FBE26726D-B8E5-47C8-9A18-504D23B99090_")[1]) ?? -1
return firstIndex < secondIndex
}
```

Comment: Different devices have different UDID so static separation with UDID like this is not good.

Comment: @SShahid I am no where seeing that OP is said its common. Can you highlight. If its common then it must be common for a user not for the entire users.

Comment: @SShahid I just tried it in playground, it didn't work. It printed out exactly the same

Comment: I have added the starting array that I used. Are you using something else?

Comment: Nope, same exact starting array. Let c+p your and see what happens

Comment: Is that `UUID` is common for all users? This is same in the case of a single user, right?

Comment: @VinuJacob a user takes several photos, I run a loop on all of them and turn them into data then create a firebase ref and append the uuid,underscore, and count to the ref. In the db completion block a url is returned for each photo and the url contains the uuid,underscore, and count. That’s why the data in the array are all http strings, they are all returned from fb with the uuid added to them. I have a property that generates the uuid and using shahid’s answer I can always access it.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array this way

- Convert the strings (back) to URL.
- Get the `lastPathComponent` of each URL.
- extract the substring from the last underscore character to the end.
- Compare the strings with `compare:` and `numeric` option or `localizedStandardCompare:`